# Getting a Random Sample of An Account's Twitter Followers

Tags: random, twitter

I am trying to get a random sample of an account's twitter followers. I found the following code: https://gist.github.com/aparrish/2910772

However, when I run it, I inevitably get 
 sname = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

What should I do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the script says on line 3 in the comment at the top of the file, when you execute the script you must specify the name of the Twitter account on the command line.

Comment: Putting the name in where? On line 20?

Comment: Put the name on the command line.  You're running it by entering something like `python random_followers.py`, right?  Instead use `python random_followers.py shakira`  Replace `shakira` by the Twitter screen name of the account whose followers you want to see.  But now that I look at the rest of the script, it won't work anyway.  The interface URL it uses is ancient. Twitter shut it down ages ago.